# How do I bypass authentication check for some pages in Blazor web assembly?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am using dotnet 7 blazor web assembly with .net core hosted server project. I am using identity server authentication and authorization. I want some page to view anonymously. Could not find any perfect way to configure my Client project not to check authentication for some pages. How do I do that?
Here is my current Program.cs for Client Project.

```
using DotnetExpert.BlazorPWA.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("DotnetExpert.BlazorPWA.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("DotnetExpert.BlazorPWA.ServerAPI"));

builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

And here is my App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p role="alert">You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>

    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Comment: Do you want to call an API on those 'public' pages? Because normally the HttpClient is configured to require a  JWT.

Comment: No, right now I don't want to call an API on those public pages.

Comment: When I create a new Hosted app with auth I can get at the Index and Counter pages w/o a problem. Only the FetchData is protected. So what did you use?  Create a [mre].

Comment: If I reload the app, I see Authorizing... text for like 2 sec. I have added my App.razor. See if that makes any sense